# Is the Mann–Whitney U test right for my problem, did I apply and interpret it correctly?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Sorry, I work a little isolated and I am seeking confirmation/disapproval for my approach. I hope that fits in here:

First let me try to explain the study design:

At location “a” I measured at randomly distributed points the physical condition and plant occurrence and then divided the habitat availability by their utilization. The result is a “physical habitat suitability index” (phsi). Now I want to use the phsi to predict plant occurrence for other (close) locations.

Therefore, at location “b” I modeled the physical environment (this model is already validated) and thereby was able to produce a map of the “phsi”. In an effort to validate the “phsi” I also field mapped the plant occurrence at location “b”.

Now I want to test whether the plants really occur where the “phsi” is higher or in other words that a randomly selected point from inside a vegetation patches has a higher phsi than a point outside.

The sample size is not equal, for the points within the patch (A) n=19 and for the points outside n=820.  Here is a sample of the data

A -> 0.8863, 0.3850, 0.6166, 0.4457, 0.4288, 0.2566, 0.3532

B -> 0.1420, 0.1882, 0.5613, 0.1360, 0.1141, 0.1328, 0.2024

When I run the test in R `wilcox.test(A,B, paired=FALSE)` my result is that `W = 13384, p-value = 4.312e-06, alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0`

My interpretation is that I can reject the null hypothesis or in other words that the plants really grow according to the growth condition index. Did I choose a good approach to test my hypothesis? Can you think of a better Method? I actually want to run the test for different species where the results are not so obvious (likely with higher p value).

Then I have doubts on how to present the data for a publication. Because I want to run the test for different plant species Iam thinking of a table with the following columns:

species, occupied, unoccupied, median occupied, median unoccupied, p

I would leave out the W value because I do not consider it very interesting for my question. Do you agree?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt the assumption of independence will be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for you comment Glen. I guess I know where your doubts come from and edited my question accordingly. In my opinion independence is given.

Comment: @Glen_b Like I said, I do not have many people around to discuss the topic: does anybody who has read my edited post still doubt that the assumption of independence is given? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I don't see that you have established independence and I still doubt it would be (even approximately) the case. Why does the protocol you added some detail on make the observations independent?

Comment: @Glen_b Through my edit I wanted to make clear that I didn’t measure the same plants twice but at different locations. Other than that I have troubles to see an independence issue. The assumption of independence demands that a) the two groups are independent (group A is inside the patch, group B is outside) and b) that each observations is also independent (each point is selected randomly).
Btw: I edited the explanation of the study design once again

Comment: It was clear in the original post that you didn't measure the same plants twice. My concern arises because of things like varying proximity in space where a variety of variables to do with soil, shade, water table, exposure to wind, etc etc can cause conditions across a set of locations to be more or less alike. For example two positions that are relatively close together are more likely to be similar than two positions that are far apart.

Comment: That is of course a very good point. Thanks for the hint! I have to think through it and will let you know how I plan to deal with it.